# Laravel log file based on date

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

By default laravel saves the log file to a single log file called laravel.log located in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

my question is how can i get a new log file everyday and store the log files like `/storage/logs/laravel-2016-02-23.log` for the current date, so i need everyday a new log file saved to `/storage/logs/`

i think we can do that by extending the default `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging` bootstraper class but i'm not sure how i can do that

i would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's actually a lot simpler than that. In your `config/app.php` you'll see the line:

```
'log' => 'single',
```

closer to the bottom of the file. Laravel by default uses the `single` method, which stores all errors in a single, expanding file. If you change this line to:

```
'log' => 'daily',
```

it will tell Laravel that you'd prefer to have multiple logs, each suffixed with the date of the when the error occurs.

There's a few other methods available, so be sure to check out the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors) for more info.

---

This answer is for Laravel 5.2, which is the version specified in the original question. In never versions of Laravel, the Logging config has been moved to it's own config file, as seen by @ShanthaKumara's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816907/3965631). Please do not suggest edits to change this answer to reflect the new version.

Answer (score 68):

In the version of **Laravel 5.6** that I am using, the configuration file for logging is **config/logging.php**

There you will find the following section

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
    ],
    ...
]
```

Change the line

```
'channels' => ['single'],
```

into

```
'channels' => ['daily'],
```

Then it will be like:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
    ],
    ...
]
```

It will create log files for each day in the format **`laravel-2018-08-13.log`** in the logs directory.
The log directory will be like

**Previously**
[image]

**After applying rotation configuration** the directory is having the log file created for the current date (as circled one which is created for today **2018-08-13**).
[image]

Comment: The `stack` driver is making it possible to use multiple drivers at the same time. If you don't need that, you can simply set the default to `daily` instead of `stack`. You can do that by setting it in your `.env` file as `LOG_CHANNEL=daily`

Comment: Keep in mind that the `daily` driver deletes the logs after the amount of days set under the `days` key . To keep them forever, just set it to `0`.

Comment: not working , i have set from many days       'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'daily'), but not working . single file  laravel.log being generate.

Comment: @totymedli out of curiosity, where one can find detail in Laravel docs which says if we set 0 to days it will not delete the logs. I have hard time figuring out which params channel supports and what they do. i can't find it in laravel docs.

Comment: @DS9 Just search for `daily` in the framework source code. In [`LogManager`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e5b86f2efec2959fb0e85ad5ee5de18f430643c4/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php#L282-L283) they pass the value to Monolog's [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php#L133-L136) where the value is checked and if it is `0` the GC is turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I have mostly worked through Yii framework and it provides documentation for every params it support. So lack of this kind of documentation in laravel is frustrating.

Answer (score 20):

just open .env file and change

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

to

```
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

then run the command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

now i think your problem will solve.

Answer (score 4):

To generate a new file for everyday in Laravel, all you need to do is change 'channels' value in the \config\logging.php file from 'single' to 'daily'.

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

The laravel on daily logging is fine, but on 1st year, you will have 365 files of `laravel.log`. My approach is to do the following on the `'path'` of the `'single'` channel.

```
storage_path('logs/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/' . date("d") . '/' . 'laravel.log')
```

This way you have organize the logs by each year/month/day.

- 2021/

  - 06/

    - 01/

      - laravel.log

Comment: I like this suggestion. However, Laravel 8 caches configuration. This means the cache would need to be cleared every day at midnight. What was your solution?

Comment: Hey @John Hanley. Can you elaborate a better question, I don't know what caching has in relation with logging.

Comment: Laravel caches the logging configuration. Your date would become static and not change each day.

Comment: Laravel doesn't cache logging config. The database cache driver to load the logging files is unecessary and unpractic.

Comment: What version are you using? Laravel 8 caches the logging configuration in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Comment: I use 8.X and all the paths in the `config` folder on `logging.php` file by default point to 
`'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log')`.

Check laravel 8.X

 [repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/logging.php).