# add current date to log's filename in Supervisor

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I use **Supervisor** to run my **Laravel** app queues.
I want to store logs of each day in different log files.

for example:

```
supervisor-2020-05-20.log
supervisor-2020-05-21.log
supervisor-2020-05-22.log
supervisor-2020-05-23.log
```

how can I do that in my config file? my current config file is like the below:

`stdout_logfile = supervisor.log`

Comment: Use `logrotate` to rotate the log daily. Are you asking about a `docker` environment?

Comment: [laravel log file based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587239/laravel-log-file-based-on-date)

Comment: @KamilCuk no, its not related to docker environment.

Comment: @Luuk i didn't ask about Laravel logs! its about supervisor logging (http://supervisord.org/logging.html)

Comment: Then `logrotate` should be a good answer...