# No logs files being written with Laravel 8 on local machine

Tags: php, laravel

I am using my local Mac machine to develop a Laravel app; while running some tests I have some lines in my code to store values in my Log file like this:

```
Log::debug('Have reached command with the following ID: ' . $post_id);
```

My .env file contents

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG=daily
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

When the method runs, no errors are returned (in debug mode, so any errors should be shown).

When I navigate to `/storage/logs/` nothing is found.

Can someone explain what might be the cause of this? I have already chmod'ed the log directory to 755.

Comment: How about to chmod 766?

Comment: Just tried that, no difference

Comment: And if you create log file there manually? Does app find it?

Comment: Check the syslog for any errors

Comment: @apokryfos Nothing appears in my sys log (mac console)

Comment: @TomášStaník I have manually tried creating the laravel.log file and setting to 755 and that is not updated at all

Comment: you have APP_LOG=daily, so filename is like app_name_2021_11_19.log

Comment: @Invalid, stop using `755`,  this means read(4) and execute(1), write is 2, then add them together for the permissions you need, so 7,5,5 means owner read+write+execute, group members read+execute, everybody read+execute, with a log file nothing should be executing it, so should be 664, the directory holding the files should be 755 because to browser a directory in shell it needs execution

Comment: You're really lacking in detail here. What user is Laravel running as, what is the ownership and permissions for the storage directory? This seems like it should be a fairly trivial problem to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd configure `Monolog` in `config/logging.php`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816907/549372 ...while your config might be cached - and therefore it might not pick up recent changes, until it had been re-cached with `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache`. I think for storage facilities there's also a `php artisan` command. For logs there's `php artisan tail`.

Use `ls -la` and/or `chown -R user:group ./storage/logs` to ensure that the owner's user & group is `apache` or `www-data` (whatever this may be on your system), because the digits of the octal permissions are always relative to the owner's group/user; then it could even be set to `600`.

The default `.env` has no `APP_LOG` either.

Comment: How does the link you've provided, or the first paragraph at all, have anything to do with permissions problems?